# all rows from the first table joined with the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table `exam`

```
ID | Name | Date
_____________________
1  | E1   | 2017-1-1
1  | E2   | 2017-1-2
1  | E3   | 2017-1-3
```

and this table `enroll`

```
ID | U_ID | E_ID | Status
_________________________
1  | 1    | 1    | 0
1  | 1    | 2    | 1
1  | 2    | 1    | 1
```

the results I want are

```
Name | U_ID | Date     | Status
_______________________________
E1   | 1    | 2017-1-1 | 0
E2   | 1    | 2017-1-2 | 1
E3   | 1    | 2017-1-3 | NULL
```

I tried this :

```
SELECT Name , U_ID , Date , Status 
FROM exam LEFT JOIN enroll ON exam.ID = enroll.E_ID
WHERE U_ID = 1
```

the result I got this

```
Name | U_ID | Date     | Status
_______________________________
E1   | 1    | 2017-1-1 | 0
E2   | 1    | 2017-1-2 | 1
```

Also tried this :

```
SELECT Name , U_ID , Date , Status 
FROM exam LEFT OUTER JOIN enroll ON exam.ID = enroll.E_ID
WHERE U_ID = 1
```

but the same results.

what is wrong ? how can I get the desired results ?

Comment: It is not possible to get your last result from the data you provide using the queries you provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the filter to `ON` condition

```
SELECT Name , U_ID , Date , Status 
FROM exam e
LEFT JOIN enroll en
       ON e.ID = en.E_ID
      AND en.U_ID = 1
```

When you use the filter where clause, for the non matching records `U_ID` will be `NULL` so it will filtered in result. When you use the filer in `ON` condition it says what are the records to be joined instead of filtering.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `WHERE` condition to `ON` to get true `left join` result (instead of `inner join` result.)

```
SELECT Name , U_ID , Date , Status 
FROM exam LEFT JOIN enroll ON exam.ID = enroll.E_ID
  AND U_ID = 1
```